How to define a nested dictionary argument of arbitrary depth
How do I define a function in Mojo where the argument is a nested structure, like a dictionary. But where the exact structure is not known at compile time because, for example, it is read from disk.
I read in the docs that Mojo doesn't natively support heterogeneous collections.
Example 1: Model parameters
How do I type annotate params in the function neural_network to represent a nested structure to keep the model parameters (i.e., a pytree).
network_params = {
  'linear1': {'weights': Tensor(...), 'bias': 1.0},
  ...
}

fn neural_network(params: Dict, x: Tensor) -> Float64:
  x = params['linear1']['weights'] @ x + params['linear1']['bias']
  ...
  return x

x_input = Tensor(...)
y = neural_network(network_params, x_input)

Example 2: JSON parsing
How do I type annotate payload in the function parse_response when it represents parsed JSON:
response = {
  'user': 'Alice',
  'address': {'street': 'Mercer Street', 'number': 112, 'city': 'Princeton'},
}
fn parse_response(payload: Dict) -> String:
  return 'Hi' + payload['user']

parse_response(response)

